# Show bus concatenation in schematic

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, kicad

How would you go about showing the concatenation of two buses in a schematic (preferably KiCad or Eagle).

For example suppose a component has `z` as an input, where `z` is 32-bit. Suppose `z` is fed by a concatenation of bus signal `x` which is 16-bit, and bus signal `y` which is 16-bit.

How would you draw signals x, y, and z in the schematic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In KiCad, you denote a bus-bus connection with a junction dot like this:

[image: KiCad Bus Connection]

Here, the numeric suffixes denote which members are connected. PCA0 and ADR0 are connected.  PCA5, ADR5 and BUS5 are also connected.  **NOTE**: PCA11 - PCA15 are not connected in this diagram.

See [KiCad Eeschema Documentation](http://docs.kicad-pcb.org/stable/en/eeschema.html#global-connections-between-buses) for more details.

---

**Edit to include mechanism for joining non-identical bus suffixes**

Suppose you want to concatenate two buses `A[0..7]` and `B[0..7]` with the larger bus `C[0..15]`. The following image illustrates how you might approach this:

[image: KiCad Bus Concatenation]

Here, we create elements for `B` that did not previously exist.  Once they exist, you can join `A[0..7]` to `B[8..15]` and `C[0..15]` to get a bus concatenation.

Comment: Ah thank you! I had been reading the "Getting Started" part of the docs. Didn't realize there was more to it, will read up on the link shared =)

Comment: How does the example above work? I assumed `PCA` was the result of joining `ADR` and `BUS`. However `PCA` is 16 bits, while `ADR` is 8 and `BUS` is 6 which is 14 bits (2 shy of `PCA`'s bit width)... I accepted the answer without carefully studying the diagram =/

Comment: What would the diagram look like if `PCA[0..15]` was the result of merging the buses `A[0..7]` and `B[0..7]`?

Comment: This works like a junction in that there is no directionality.  It matches the numerical suffix when joining individual nets.

Comment: If you have a junction between `A[0..7]` and `PCA[0..15]`, then `A0` and `PCA0` would be joined but `PCA8` would be dangling.  Adding `B[0..7]` to the junction joins `A0`, `B0` and `PCA0`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So what would be the way to join two distinct buses `A[0..7]` (e.g. upper byte) and `B[0..7]` (e.g. lower byte) to make bus `C[0..15]`? Does one write `B[8..15]`??

Comment: You would need to join the nets individually at the moment (KiCad v5.0).  Group concatenation or splicing is not yet supported.  In other words, make a set of local labels joining `B0`-`B8`, `B1`-`B9`, etc.  Then join A, B and C as shown in the diagram above.

Comment: Hi Seth, sorry I don't understand ("...make a set of local labels joining B0-B8, B1-B9, etc. Then join A, B and C..."). Are you able to update the answer with an image of this?

Comment: Thanks again for your time. I created [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7QBT.png) based on yours to clearly illustrate the approach. If it is accurate, do you mind if I update your answer with it?

Comment: Please do!  Yours is definitely an improvement!